# Select where next row's value is greater

Tags: oracle, select, oracle-12c, time

I have a `road_insp` table.

```
  create table road_insp
   (    
    insp_id int,
    road_id int,
    insp_date date, 
    condition number(38,2)
   ) ;

insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (1,1,to_date('01-JAN-01','DD-MON-YY'),10);
insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (2,1,to_date('01-JAN-04','DD-MON-YY'),09);
insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (3,1,to_date('01-JAN-07','DD-MON-YY'),08);
insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (4,1,to_date('01-JAN-10','DD-MON-YY'),06);

insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (5,2,to_date('01-JAN-02','DD-MON-YY'),10);
insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (6,2,to_date('01-JAN-05','DD-MON-YY'),08);

insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (7,4,to_date('01-JAN-03','DD-MON-YY'),10);
insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (8,4,to_date('01-JAN-06','DD-MON-YY'),12);
insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (9,4,to_date('01-JAN-09','DD-MON-YY'),08);

insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (10,5,to_date('01-JAN-01','DD-MON-YY'),10);
insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (11,5,to_date('01-JAN-03','DD-MON-YY'),09);
insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (12,5,to_date('01-JAN-06','DD-MON-YY'),08);
insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (13,5,to_date('01-JAN-09','DD-MON-YY'),07);
insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (14,5,to_date('01-JAN-12','DD-MON-YY'),06);
insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (15,5,to_date('01-JAN-15','DD-MON-YY'),05);
insert into road_insp (insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition) values (16,5,to_date('01-JAN-18','DD-MON-YY'),20);

select
    *
from
    road_insp
order by
    road_id,
    insp_date



   INSP_ID    ROAD_ID   INSP_DATE  CONDITION
---------- ----------   --------- ----------
         1          1   01-JAN-01         10
         2          1   01-JAN-04          9
         3          1   01-JAN-07          8
         4          1   01-JAN-10          6

         5          2   01-JAN-02         10
         6          2   01-JAN-05          8

         7          4   01-JAN-03         10
         8          4   01-JAN-06         12 <-error
         9          4   01-JAN-09          8

        10          5   01-JAN-01         10
        11          5   01-JAN-03          9
        12          5   01-JAN-06          8
        13          5   01-JAN-09          7
        14          5   01-JAN-12          6
        15          5   01-JAN-15          5
        16          5   01-JAN-18         20 <-error
```

For each road, I want to know if the condition ever goes **UP** over time. The idea being, roads don't just magically improve in condition.

If the condition of the road ever goes up, then the culprit inspection should be flagged.

How can I analyze this table to find anomalies (conditions that go up)?

Example:

```
      INSP_ID   ROAD_ID     COND_ERROR_DATE  COND_ERROR
    ---------- ----------   ---------------- ----------
            8           4   01-JAN-06                12
           16           5   01-JAN-18                20
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select
  insp_id, road_id, insp_date as cond_error_date, condition as cond_error 
from 
(
  select
    insp_id, road_id, insp_date, condition, 
    lag(condition) over (partition by road_id order by insp_date) as condition_before
  from
    road_insp
)
where condition > condition_before;

   INSP_ID    ROAD_ID COND_ERRO COND_ERROR
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
         8          4 01-JAN-06         12
        16          5 01-JAN-18         20
```